# Toggle Button Value to Integer

Tags: java, android

I want to add a toggle button that contains an integer value. if the toggle button is checked, the value is 1, and vice versa. how do I get this value from the toggle button?

Sample code welcome. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you attempted to code the button already? Can you share what you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
final int answer = 0;
JToggleButton jtb = new JToggleButton("Press Me");
jtb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
       if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
           answer = 1;
       } else if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
           answer = 0;
       }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle button can be created by making a custom widget inheriting Button class.

```
class SelectableButton(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : Button(context, attrs) {
    var isViewSelected: Boolean = false

    init {
        setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.black))
        background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.yellow_selector)
    }

    fun getSelectedInt() = if(isViewSelected) 1 else 0

    override fun performClick(): Boolean {
        isViewSelected = !isViewSelected
        background = if (isViewSelected) {
            setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.black))
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.yellow_selector)
        } else {
            setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.black))
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.grey_rounded_corner)
        }
        return super.performClick()
    }
```

In above code text color and background is also toggled for selected state. You can remove if you don't need.

**Example Usage**

```
// In layout file
<com.your.package.SelectableButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button text"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

// In code
// toggle in programming is not necessary

// get selected value
val intValue = button.getSelectedInt()
```